# Ansible: set ssh arguments using group variables

Tags: ssh, ansible

To connect to different groups of hosts, I need to use different ssh config files. I'm currently trying to connect to both groups in the same playbook, but I can't figure out how to change `ssh_args` within the playbook. I was wondering if I could use `group_vars` to do this?

The way I currently set `ssh_args` is in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ./ssh.cfg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you should use `ansible_ssh_common_args`, see [List of Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Comment: What if you need to replace some of the SSH arguments instead of just adding them? `ansible_ssh_common_args` seems to only append arguments.